# Is there any way to simplify $ADA^T$ from a computational standpoint, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix, not necessarily symmetric, and $D$ be a diagonal $n \times n$ matrix. In my problem, $m < n$ but both $m$ and $n$ have the potential to be quite large, so the computation of $ADA^T$ can take a few seconds as the dimensions get really high. Algebraically, is there any way to simplify this expression since $D$ is a diagonal matrix? I'd like to find something that takes less time to compute in R.

Comment: The computation $AD$ simply multiplies each column of $A$ by one of the diagonal entries of $D$; this should be pretty quick if implemented directly or if $D$ is encoded as a sparse matrix. From there, I don't think that the computation $(AD)A^T$ can be shortened

Comment: If you're doing repeated computations here, are there certain aspects that you expect will change? For example, will you be using the same $D$ but different matrices for $A$? The same $A$ but different matrices for $D$?